# How to prevent download manager to download file from <canvas>

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, pdf.js

Currently I'm working with a low-scale project. In my project I viewed some pdf using `pdf.js`. I do mange to hide top bar and download or print button. I just want viewer can only read it instead of downloading or printing it. But the problem is, the document is being auto-downloaded in a browser that has a download manager. Download manager like IDM grabbing the file on page load.

Is there any solution to this problem now?

My JS code are given bellow!

Thank you 
Nazmul Hossain

```
let pdfDoc = null,
  pageNum = 1,
  pageIsRendering = false,
  pageNumIsPending = null;

const scale = 1.5,
  canvas = document.querySelector('#pdf-render'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


const renderPage = num => {
  pageIsRendering = true;


  pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(page => {
  
    const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale });
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    const renderCtx = {
      canvasContext: ctx,
      viewport
    };

    page.render(renderCtx).promise.then(() => {
      pageIsRendering = false;

      if (pageNumIsPending !== null) {
        renderPage(pageNumIsPending);
        pageNumIsPending = null;
      }
    });

    document.querySelector('#page-num').textContent = num;
  });
};

const queueRenderPage = num => {
  if (pageIsRendering) {
    pageNumIsPending = num;
  } else {
    renderPage(num);
  }
};

const showPrevPage = () => {
  if (pageNum <= 1) {
    return;
  }
  pageNum--;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
};


const showNextPage = () => {
  if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
    return;
  }
  pageNum++;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
};


pdfjsLib
  .getDocument(url)
  .promise.then(pdfDoc_ => {
    pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;

    document.querySelector('#page-count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

    renderPage(pageNum);
  })
  .catch(err => {
  
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'error';
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(err.message));
    document.querySelector('body').insertBefore(div, canvas);
    
    document.querySelector('.top-bar').style.display = 'none';
  });


document.querySelector('#prev-page').addEventListener('click', showPrevPage);
document.querySelector('#next-page').addEventListener('click', showNextPage);
```

**UPDATE** 
Although I failed come up with a solution of this problem but I manage some thing else.
I just encrypt the pdf file then view it by pdf.js. So even if someone manage to download it they can't open it. Just change a line here -

```
pdfjsLib.getDocument({url: 'file-url', password: 'file-password'})
```

Thank You
Nazmul Hossain

Comment: as far as i know you can't do it.but you can add watermark to your pdf.

Comment: Yes I know that. I can do that manually.